# Does Elixir have a HTTP routing library?

Tags: web-services, routes, url-routing, elixir

I'm interested in using Elixir for a web service type project, for that I will need it to be able to do routing such as that found in Rails or Rack. Does such a thing exist in Elixir?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes.  Take a look at:

- Elixir Plug: https://github.com/elixir-lang/plug
- Elixir Phoenix: https://github.com/phoenixframework/phoenix
- Hex.pm for a listing of various Elixir packages.